# webstorm file watcher not working on one file

Tags: typescript, webstorm, file-watcher

We are currently working with TypeScript in Webstorm. We setup the fileWatcher a while a go. Everything was working fine. Yesterday, the file watcher stop working on one file, at least that I noticed. The other script file are working fine, but in this file I need to delete the `js` file that are compiled to force a new creation of the file.

The error happens in webstorm 8 and the latest release of webstorm 9 (138.2406). In the webstorm 9, the event logger rises the following error : `AssertionError: null`

Does anyone else have that error?

Also, the transpiled file are not place under the ts file.

Comment: does this file have syntax errors? Can you check if the problem persists after enabling 'trigger watcher regardless of syntax errors' option?

Comment: I can also suggest invalidating caches (File/invalidate caches, restart). If nothing helps, please contact support, providing the idea.log, watcher settings and (preferrably) the project/file that shows up the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would appears that the documentation above the function is important for the transpiler. Thous having a `@returns` line with no information on what the function returns won't let the transpiler do it work.

It took us some time to find it, but if anyone have the issue this is how we fixed it.